# How to insert userinput into Azure SQL database using JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sql-server, azure

I am trying to insert userinput into Azure SQL database using JavaScript
and here is my JavaScript code:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email')

var username = document.getElementById('username')

var password = document.getElementById('password')

const { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");

// Create connection to database
const config = {
    authentication: {
        options: {
            userName: "*********", 
            password: "*********" 
        },
        type: "default"
    },
    server: "**************", 
    options: {
        database: "********", 
        encrypt: true
    }
};

const connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on("connect", err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        queryDatabase();
    }
});

function queryDatabase() {
    console.log("Inserting data into the Table...");

    // Read all rows from table
    const request = new Request(
        `INSERT INTO [dbo].[dbo] (email, username, password)
  VALUES ('${username}', '${email}', '${password}');
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[dbo] `,
        (err, rowCount) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log(`${rowCount} row(s) returned`);
            }
        }
    );

    request.on("row", columns => {
        columns.forEach(column => {
            console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
        });
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/register.css" />
    <script src="../js/connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="../Subpages/account.html">Log in</a>
        <a href="https://exampletonyhuang.azurewebsites.net/">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="../Subpages/shoppingcart.html">Shopping Cart</a>
        <a href="../Subpages/billinginfo.html">Billing info</a>
    </div>
    <div class="register-box">

        <br /><br /><center><h1><b>Register Account</b></h1></center>

        <form class="userinput-box">
            <center>
                <h3>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required></h3>
                <br /><h3>Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></h3>
                <br /><h3>Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></h3>
            </center>
        </form>

        <center>
            <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="queryDatabase()"><br />

        </center>
    </div>
</body>      
</html>
```

I tried my JavaScript code in `node.js` project, it worked. but when I moved the code to a ASP.NET project, it shows that `const { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");`

> require is not defined

and when I click the button to save userinput, it shows that Uncaught ReferenceError:

> Cannot access 'Request' before initialization for

```
const request = new Request(
 `INSERT INTO [dbo].[dbo] (email, username, password)
  VALUES ('${username}', '${email}', '${password}');
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[dbo] `," Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Request' before initialization
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 'tedious' Getting started website the initialization should be:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
```

I am not entirely sure if your call does the same but it may pay to visit their 'Getting Started' page? http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/getting-started.html

For the second part is more clear:

The function call to `new Request()` is made before it is initialized, likely as a result of the earlier error? As it seems to be that you are trying to initialize `Connection` and `Request` but the initialization should be as per above?

Because that would actually assign the `require('tedious').Connection` to the variable `Connection`.